# Are the first 4 statistical moments independent?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, st.statistics, moments

Are the first 4 statistical moments independent? Is there a mathematical demonstration that can show independence one from each other? Can the value of one moment influence the value of another? If so, can they be separated? Can they create an orthogonal basis?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the moments of a real-valued random variable, they are not independent in the sense that they are related by inequalities, e.g. $\mathbb E[X^2] \ge \mathbb E[X]^2$.